# C: TIFFWriteEncodedStrip vs Java:?

Tags: java, tiff, fax

In Java, how could the same byte array be written to a tiff file using TIFFImageWriter, after creating an associated TIFFDirectory configured with TIFFFields

### Haven't seen any Java parallels yet.

More info

Compression: T4_COMPRESSION_T4_1D

In https://github.com/freeswitch/spandsp/blob/master/src/t4_t6_decode.c

Per line of compressed fax image:

/* Convert the runs to a bit image of the row */

```
/* White/black/white... runs, always starting with white. 
    That means the first run could be zero length. */

        for (x = 0, fudge = 0;  x < s->a_cursor;  x++, fudge ^= 0xFF)
        {
            i = s->cur_runs[x];
            if ((int) i >= s->pixels)
            {
                s->pixel_stream = (s->pixel_stream << s->pixels) |
                                  (msbmask[s->pixels] & fudge);
                for (i += (8 - s->pixels);  i >= 8;  i -= 8)
                {
                    s->pixels = 8;
                    s->row_buf[row_pos++] = (uint8_t) s->pixel_stream;
                    s->pixel_stream = fudge;
                }
            }
            s->pixel_stream = (s->pixel_stream << i) | (msbmask[i] & fudge);
            s->pixels -= i;
        }
        s->image_length++;
```

Each row_buf bytes get accumulated in image_buffer for a page,
and in t4_rx.c  write_tiff_image(t4_rx_state_t *s), the strip
is written to file via:

```
 /* Let libtiff do the compression */
 TIFFWriteEncodedStrip(t->tiff_file, 0, t->image_buffer, t->image_size)
```

Q: To do this in java, how would the byte array that contains the page
pixels/bits be passed to a TiffImageWriter object ?

Comment: Different libraries and frameworks do things differently. There might not be a direct analogue between the C and Java libraries you use. If you want to write a TIFF file using Java and the library you have for it, study the documentation for that library, and try to find examples using that specific library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ImageIO has extensive [TIFF metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/tiff_metadata.html).  When you say “the same byte array,” are you referring to uncompressed 1-bit pixels (eight pixels per byte), or compressed T.4 data?

Comment: I added more info and clarified the question

Comment: The obvious answer to *"Q: To do this in java, how would the byte array that contains the page pixels/bits be passed to a TiffImageWriter object?"* is `imageWriter.write(image)` (or possibly an overload with more parameters, if you want to control compression etc). Where image is a `BufferedImage` (containing the byte array with the pixels). But I suspect this is not what you are looking for? And in that case, I don't understand what you are asking, please clarify...

Answer (score 1):

I’m not entirely certain I understand your question, but it appears your byte array contains 1-bit pixel information packed into bytes.

You can create a BufferedImage based on those bytes, then write it as a TIFF using [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/package-summary.html).

First, one makes a BufferedImage from the data:

- Wrap the byte array in a [DataBufferByte](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/DataBufferByte.html)
- [Create a Raster](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/Raster.html#createPackedRaster(java.awt.image.DataBuffer,int,int,int,java.awt.Point)), specifying that it should treat the buffer’s bytes as 1-bit pixels packed into bytes.
- Create a [ColorModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html) indicating how the 1-bit pixels are to be written.
- Finally, create a BufferedImage from that Raster and ColorModel.

```java
DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(pixels, pixels.length);
WritableRaster raster =
    Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1, null);

byte[] colors = { 0x00, (byte) 0xff };  // 0=black, 1=white
ColorModel colorModel =
    new IndexColorModel(1, colors.length, colors, colors, colors);

BufferedImage image =
    new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, new Properties());
```

The [ImageIO TIFF metadata specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/tiff_metadata.html#Compression) describes how to specify TIFF compression:

```
ImageWriter tiffWriter =
    ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();

ImageWriteParam param = tiffWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();

param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("CCITT T.4");

IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);

try (ImageOutputStream out = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(
        Files.newOutputStream(filename)))) {

    tiffWriter.setOutput(out);
    tiffWriter.write(null, iioImage, param);
} finally {
    tiffWriter.dispose();
}
```

Here is the full method:

```
public void writeTIFF(byte[] pixels,
                      int imageWidth,
                      int imageHeight,
                      Path filename)
throws IOException {
    DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(pixels, pixels.length);
    WritableRaster raster =
        Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1, null);

    byte[] colors = { 0x00, (byte) 0xff };  // 0=black, 1=white
    ColorModel colorModel =
        new IndexColorModel(1, colors.length, colors, colors, colors);

    BufferedImage image =
        new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, new Properties());

    ImageWriter tiffWriter =
        ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();

    ImageWriteParam param = tiffWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();

    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionType("CCITT T.4");

    IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);

    try (ImageOutputStream out = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            Files.newOutputStream(filename)))) {

        tiffWriter.setOutput(out);
        tiffWriter.write(null, iioImage, param);
    } finally {
        tiffWriter.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked for my experiment. I'm guessing that the  colors[] definition overrides the TAG_PHOTOMETRIC_INTERPRETATION field, since the image remains the same for either WHITE_IS_ZERO or BLACK_IS_ZERO.  I think I'll stick with the C libtiff whenever possible.

Comment: These are of course completely different abstraction levels. ImageIO API is high level and file format agnostic (the above code would also work to write a PNG, BMP, GIF or any other format that supports bilevel, by only changing the format name and compression type), while libtiff is low level and TIFF-specific. 